# JSF 1.2 hx selectone menu, on change update content without page refresh

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a page with a selectOneMenu and I was wondering if there is any way that I can update a content in another div without a page refresh.
I am trying this right now and this doesnt work. I know that I can do onChange="submit()", but that refreshes the page, I dont want the page to refresh
Also, would this be possible with hx:behavior and/or ajaxRefreshSubmit?
If yes can someone show me a simple example to achieve that. Thanks for the help

```
<hx:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.myValue}"
    valueChangeListener="#{controller.valueChangeMethod}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.values}" />
</hx:selectOneMenu>

<div id="divToBeUpdated">
#{bean.displayValue}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you  could use  ajax for above purpose. here is sample code

```
<h:form id="welcome">
<h:selectOneMenu id="countrydropdown" value="#{pracBB.mycountry}" >
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="India" itemValue="ind"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="usa" itemValue="usa"/>
<a4j:support event="onchange"  action="#{pracBB.changeData}" reRender="welcome">        </a4j:support>
 </h:selectOneMenu>



<h:outputText value="#{pracBB.dynamicString}"/>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean code 
private String mycountry;

```
private String dynamicString="default";


public void changeData()

{



    if(mycountry.equalsIgnoreCase("usa"))
    {
        dynamicString="you have selected usa";  
    }

    else
    {
        dynamicString="you have selected india";

    }

}
```